# openui5 sapui5 ODataV4 Create and Server-Side ID

Tags: odata, sapui5

Given OPENUI5 with an ODataV4 data source.

Now, when I create an entity and submit it to the server, it returns the newly generated ID of the entity. I would like to use this to directly navigate to the newly generated entity upon creation with the Navigation feature of OPENUI5.

However, my initial idea with

```
obj.created().then(function () {
    var id = obj.getProperty("Id");
    ...
});
```

Does not work as the Id property is not populated although the server correctly returns it.

How can I retrieve the newly created object including the server-side generated properties?

Thanks, regards

Jörg Fischer

Comment: this could be due to local caching. does the server return `HTTP 200` or `HTTP 201`? if the latter is the case, then you should receive a `Location` header with a link (incl `Id`) to the newly created resource which you can navigate. If not then you would have to reload the entity.

Comment: I have never used V4 ODataModel. From the source code https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/resources/sap/ui/model/odata/v4/ODataModel-dbg.js , why the getProperty method is not implemented like most of the methods? Can you switch to V2 ODataModel?

Comment: Hi,correct, there is a Location header available as the server returns HTTP 201. However, how can I access this though OPENUI5 ? Changing to OData V2 is not an option as the backend only support ODATA v3 / v4.